# How to show a Snackbar from a Stream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, stream

I want to show a `SnackBar` once a `Stream` of `String` sends a new `String`.

I tried to place a `StreamBuilder` inside a `StatefulWidget`, in order to be able to call `Scaffold.of()` (since it's another `context` now). but then I get this error:

> The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
>   _StreamBuilderBaseState>#7f258):
>   setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
>   This Scaffold widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
>   process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
>   only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
>   builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
>   Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
>   The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
>     Scaffold(dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#0e1f6], Directionality, _InheritedTheme,
>     MediaQuery], state: ScaffoldState#3f2aa(tickers: tracking 2 tickers))
>   The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
>     StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState>#7f258)

**How can I solve this?**

This a simple code snippet showing the problem:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TestHome(),
    );
  }
}

class TestHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamSnackbar(),
    );
  }
}

class StreamSnackbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StreamSnackbarState createState() => _StreamSnackbarState();
}

class _StreamSnackbarState extends State<StreamSnackbar> {
  final status = StreamController<String>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                status.add('Test');
              },
              child: Text('Press me to trigger the Snackbar!'),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<String>(
              stream: status.stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(snapshot.data)));
                }
                return Container(
                  height: 0,
                  width: 0,
                ); // just because we need to return a Widget
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show some code also.

Comment: My code is very big to post here, I will try a simple example, but its basically `Scaffold`->`NewWiget`->`StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use a `StreamBuilder`. Showing the `SnackBar` has to be done outside of sync `build()` execution anyway.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  status.stream.forEach((e) =>
    Scaffold.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e))));
}

@override
void dispose() {
  status.close();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Good point, guess I got caught into the patterns. I was thinking about using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() ` but wanted to see if there was a better option out there, thanks Gunter!

Comment: Any reasons for you to use `forEach()` instead of `listen()`? I thought `forEach` advantage was that it doesn't need to dispose the stream, but you are disposing it anyways.

Comment: it doesn't create a `StreamSubscription` instance that is only ignored anyway. `listen` was used everywhere for years but Dart language designers want to make the more efficient way the default one and I help spreading the idea ;-)

Comment: Got it...but then why the `status.close()` on `dispose()` if there's no subscription?

Comment: A `StreamController` should always be closed and `forEach` waits for the closing to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}'),
              ),
            );
          }
```

In Your StreamBuilder You have to use like this